# multipeer connectivity for streaming audio from iphone microphone

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, microphone, multipeer-connectivity

i've been trying some time now to find a way to transit sound from the iphone microphone between 2 iphones using the multipeer connectivity. There is a very nice tutorial for streaming mp3 music ( [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity) ) and another tutorial for processing the audio from mic in real time ( [here](http://www.stefanpopp.de/2011/capture-iphone-microphone/) ). I tried to combine the 2 so that instead of mp3 music to transmit the microphone feed but with no success. Do you have any better solution for this? Any other ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: hi buddy have you found any solution for your question? As I'm stuck at same point. If you have then please guide me

Comment: Did you find another solution?

Comment: @MayurCM  Have to find the solution?

Comment: @PabloMartinez did you find the  solution?

Comment: I found a solution encoding the pcm to aac into chunks and then send it to the other device

Comment: @PabloMartinez I successfully transfer the mic voice to connected peer but it works only for WiFi, not for Bluetooth, I want to transfer the voice over Bluetooth. Have you any other solution or demo project? Thanks

Comment: @SaurabhJain I used Bonjour to transfer over Bluetooth or Wifi

Comment: @PabloMartinez I don't know anything about Bonjour, could you provide some reference or demo project for understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Wha i used for this at the end was the GameKit from apple. Its deprecated now but for what i needed was good enough. Its not optimal and if you want to use a second channel it will be a problem because the output will be redirected to the telephone speaker  (The one you use for calling, not the loudspeaker). If other solution is found i might consider redesigning the app.